# SceneKit set rotation using two vectors

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, macos, graphics

I'm searching a way to easily rotate a `SCNNode` in SceneKit. So lets assume I have two vectors `h = (1 0 0)` and `u = (0 1 0)`. `h` (in my mind) point in the direction the node is heading and `u` points upwards.

After the rotation I want `h` to be `h' = (0 5 1)` and `u` to be `u' = (0 -1 -5)`. So the angle between the two vectors is still 90 degrees.

How can I rotate my `SCNNode` like that?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want to do exactly, but basically what you do is (put the code in a PlayGround):

```
import UIKit
import SceneKit
import PlaygroundSupport

let scnView = SCNView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 500, height: 500))
scnView.autoenablesDefaultLighting = true

let scene = SCNScene()
scnView.scene = scene

let light = SCNLight()
light.type = .directional
let lightNode = SCNNode()
lightNode.light = light
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(lightNode)

let camera = SCNCamera()
let cameraNode = SCNNode()
cameraNode.camera = camera
cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(0,0,10)
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)

let box = SCNBox(width: 1, height: 1, length: 1, chamferRadius: 0)
let boxNode = SCNNode(geometry: box)
boxNode.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.red
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(boxNode)

let rotateAction = SCNAction.rotateBy(x: 0, y: -1, z: 5, duration: 1)
let repeatAction = SCNAction.repeatForever(rotateAction)
SCNTransaction.begin()
SCNTransaction.animationDuration = 1
boxNode.runAction(repeatAction)
SCNTransaction.commit()

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = scnView
```

Comment: This does not fulfill the requirements. `rotateBy` rotates by an angle in radians. So if you have a vector `(1 0 0)` and rotate it by -1 radians on the y axis and by 5 radians on the z axis, you will not get the `(1 -1 5)` but something completely different.

Comment: To put it differently: If I have two nodes at the positions given in the original question and each node contains a sphere, how would I need to rotate the `rootNode`so that they end up in the desired locations from the original question?

Comment: just add them as children to an empty node, add the empty node to your scenes rootNode. When you rotate that empty node the childNodes stay at the same position. That is the basic idea behind a Scene Graph. For more information look here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scene_graph

Comment: I know how to rotate nodes. The question was about how to figure out the eulerAngles, rotationMatrix or whatever needed to apply the rotation.